# How to get custom web templates?

Tags: powershell, web-template

I have users who creates site templates and uses that template to create new sites. There are about 400 of these sites. I tried getting the site templates for these sites but it only returns the base template name.

[image]

```
Get-SPWebApplication https://projects.nova.com | get-spsite -limit all |get-spweb -limit all | select URL, webtemplate, WebTemplateId | ft -wrap -autosize | out-file -filepath "F:\Software\Scripts\Sites\All_Sites_with_WebTemplate.txt"
```

Comment: What information are you trying to get?

Comment: Go to create new sub-site and click "Custom" under the select a template. All sites are created with these custom templates. When I run the code above it gives me the generic base template and not what I see in the custom templates. Does it make sense?

Comment: I posted a picture of it.

Comment: OK, you're saying the values for WebTemplate and WebTemplateId being returned by PowerShell don't match the actual template used when the site was created. I'm not sure what's causing this. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist you.

Comment: Yes that's true.